# Does Springboot 3.0 works with gcp cloudrun?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

The issue is the app with springboot 2.7.x version works with cloud run but not with springboot 3.0.x

Comment: As per this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/spring-native-quickstart#0:~:text=Spring%20Native%20is%20set%20to%20be%20integrated%20into%20Spring%20Framework%206.0%20and%20Spring%20Boot%203.0%20with%20first%20class%20support) cloud run supports spring boot 3, Can you explain what is the problem you are facing? and what is the java version you are using?

Comment: There is no relation between a framework and Cloud Run. If you are able to start a webserver and package your code in a container, you can deploy it on Cloud Run. Test first your container.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am able to create a container and able to deploy the image from the container into the cloudrun console using serviceaccount as invoker. But every request to the cloudrun service throws 404

Comment: @RoopaM I am using java 17 and springboot 3.0 for my cloudrun service deployment. Facing 404 for every request to the deployed service

Comment: If you have a 404, your server works great, your deployment also!! Again, it's not a problem with Cloud Run but with Spring Boot. In you case, I suspect a trailing / not taken into account in your URL path. Did you try with and without?